# Mysql structure and relationship between a lot of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I have made this structure MySQL Workbench, but I dont know if the relationships are correctly added. I'm just starting in mysql, so would appreciate if you could tell me as clear as possible if they are not.

[structure MySQL image](http://puu.sh/6gVia/3f988b76f1.jpg)

If this correct, for example:
If I will delete a record of the table "sf_cadena", the records relating to the "id" would also be eliminated or will I have to make an query before deleting it?

as these "sf_proyecto" -> "sf_capitulo" -> "sf_synopsis_cap".

PS: Sorry for the bad English and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depends from your tables options. If these keys related with foreign keys, it will be use constraints onDelete and onUpdate, that you can define.

Comment: I put them all onUpdate: no action, onDelete: cascade. because I never would update a id that has already been added. 

Are only affected by _onDelete: cascade_ the tables that have the sign of infinity, right? 

By the way, while reading and looked references from this, I found that _onDelete: cascade_ can lock the database to insert, delete and update, is that true?